# Sorting nested defaultdicts in Python

Tags: python, sorting, defaultdict

I'm nesting 2 levels of default dicts. The inner dict contains a number of fields, and I would like to sort it by one of the values and delete the entries that correspond to the lowest values.

Here's a simplified code example:

```
from collections import defaultdict

sampleDict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(lambda:str)))

sampleDict['keyA']['keyB']['size'] = 1000
sampleDict['keyA']['keyC']['size'] = 500
sampleDict['keyA']['keyD']['size'] = 750
sampleDict['keyA']['keyE']['size'] = 250
sampleDict['keyA']['keyB']['desc'] = 'some data'
sampleDict['keyA']['keyC']['desc'] = 'some more data'
sampleDict['keyA']['keyD']['desc'] = 'different data'
sampleDict['keyA']['keyE']['desc'] = 'other data'
```

In this case, I want to sort and identify that the highest `size` is `['keyA']['keyB']` and that the second highest is `['keyA']['keyD']` and then remove `['keyA']['keyC']` and `['keyA']['keyE']`.

The reason it is nested is because I will then be looping through other entries in the outer dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> import operator
>>> sorted(
...     reduce(operator.add, 
...     [[(k, k1, sampleDict[k][k1]['size']) for k1 in v.keys()]
...              for k,v in sampleDict.items()]
...     ),
...     key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)
[('keyA', 'keyB', 1000), ('keyA', 'keyD', 750), ('keyA', 'keyC', 500), ('keyA', 'keyE', 250)]
```

The reduce statement is used to turn the nested list `[[a],[b,c],[d]]` into `[a,b,c]`.

The key argument for the sorted statement specifies to sort on the (zero inclusive) 2nd argument of `(k,k1,val)` ie, val.

The reverse argument orders the list in descending order.

Comment: FYI, `itertools.chain.from_iterable` will flatten values more efficiently than `reduce` + `operator.add` (which has to produce tons of intermediate `list`s). `sorted(itertools.chain.from_iterable([(k, k1, v1['size']) for k1, v1 in v.items()] for k,v in sampleDict.items()), key=operator.itemgetter(2), reverse=True)` would be faster, involving fewer intermediate `list`s and fewer lookups.

Comment: Or you avoid nesting at all; `sorted(((k, k1, v1['size']) for k, v in sampleDict.items() for k1, v1 in v.items()), key=operator.itemgetter(2), reverse=True)` should also work, and it avoids even making nested structures at all.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import heapq
>>> [(k, heapq.nlargest(2, sampleDict[k], lambda x: sampleDict[k][x]['size']))
...   for k in sampleDict]
[('keyA', ['keyB', 'keyD'])]
```

If you don't care about the difference between dict.items for Python2/3, you can also write it as

```
>>> [(k, heapq.nlargest(2, v, lambda x: v[x]['size'])) for k,v in sampleDict.items()]
[('keyA', ['keyB', 'keyD'])]
```